# can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I just installed appache, MySQL and PHP, suring my installation, I was prompted for a MySQL root user password, but when I start my MySQL, it pops the error, and I just can't seem to find a way around it, most solutions I've read doesn't solve it, moreover, I found out that the /var/run/mysqld path doesn't even exist, my php also needs the socket to connect to my Database.

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: Sudo mysql -u root -p @thefoutheye

Comment: Try `ps -eaf | grep -in mysql` and post the result

Comment: 210:1000   13296 5531  0  16:08  pts/1. 00:00:00 grep --color=auto  in mysql

Comment: How did you install mysql? with `apt-get install`?

Comment: Nope, I copied .deb mysql files from a server(ubuntu 13.04) iso file, since I don't have internet access, but even when I used apt-get install, I had the same error

Comment: What do you think I should do? @thefourtheye

Comment: Did u ever find a permanent solution ? If yes, then pls post the answer here. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 7):

After checking that /etc/mysql/my.cnf was correct (`port=3306`, `bind-address=127.0.0.1`), I was still having trouble. I then got `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` automatically by installing mysql-server:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

I then tried starting the mysql server as thefourtheye said, but still got the same error you're getting when trying to start mysql via `$ mysql -u root`.

Finally, I found a similar [discussion on ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1987870) that finally fixed it for me.

Here's the only part of the link that I found I needed to do:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Then I was able to start mysql with `$ mysql -u root -p`, using the password I set when I installed `mysql-server-5.5`

Answer (score 2):

`sudo service mysql start`

Execute this command to start the MySQL server.

Comment: I've been doing just that but nothing positive, I've found out that mysql-client is not configured, maybe fixing that would help, but I don't know how to configure mysql-client, I'm sure the server is up and good @thefourtheye

Comment: If server is up, `ps -eaf | grep -in mysql` would have shown that in the output

Comment: What shoult I do?

Answer (score 0):

I once had encountered the same error message after a MySQL update. In my case, it was caused by an invalid configuration option.

The option `–skip-locking` was deprecated in MySQL 5.1 and removed in MySQL 5.5. You'll have to use `–skip-external-locking` instead.

So check, if your configuration has a line

```
skip-locking
```

in the `[mysqld]` section. If so, change it to

```
skip-external-locking
```

Don't forget to restart the server.