# While accesing mysql in Ubuntu , after entering the correct password?

Tags: mysql

I am getting this message :

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Comment: What command you have used to be exact?

Comment: mysql -u root -p

Comment: Is the `mysql` server running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the steps below and you will be able to solve your error :

1. Install mysql-server using command `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

After that , just run below commands in your terminal :

2. `sudo service mysql stop`
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload`
4. `sudo service mysql start`

Now , run the command `mysql -u root -p` , you will successfully enter into the mysql command prompt.

Note : I too was having the same error and found this answer from [can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291054/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock?newreg=588c9e415cf2452bbc7a6c244cab808c).

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,but it didn't work.

Comment: You are getting the same error which you have mentioned in your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql server is not running. Try to set error logging in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in `[mysqld]` section : `log_error = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log` , then restart mysql and look for errors. When you fix your errors you will access your mysql.